# dataGridView Image not displaying for first row, second Cell

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

Okay so I have a dataGridView that I am trying to display an image on (using the DataGridViewImageColumn), all of the appropriate rows have the image, except for row one (this is also the only row that I can see in the visual studio's editor) The image below is what I am getting, I want all of them to be the green check mark though. How might I accomplish that?

[image]

Please note that I have already tried the following: 
Changing or removing my selection on start-up; 
Using a different image; Setting the image dynamically (in code); and a bit of randomly changing settings. Any help would be highly appreciated! I thank you all in advance for the help, please let me know if I can supply anymore information.

Comment: can you post the full image of the grid here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   namespace WindowsFormsApplication1   
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new MyItem { Key = i, value = Image.FromFile(@"e:\test.jpg") });
        }

        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Key", "Key");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn() { HeaderText="Status"});

        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Key";            
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "value";

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = items;

    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public Image value { get; set; }
}
```

}[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Eugene, I've got everything working now, good luck with any of your projects and again thank you!