# Displaying icon files in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to display icon file in datagridview column but I'm having some problems:
[see this pic](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/987930ssss.jpg)

And this is my code :

```
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:/1419608299489.jpg");
DataGridViewImageColumn image = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
image.HeaderText = "Image";
image.Icon = ico;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(image);
```

Comment: _"C:/1419608299489.jpg"_ This will not work. Prefix the string with ampersand @  and use backslash, assuming you are in the file system!  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!

Comment: sorry it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are searching for (found here [dataGridView Image not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409303/datagridview-image-not-displaying-for-first-row-second-cell)):

```
        Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"filepath");

        List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new MyItem { Key = i, value = icon.ToBitmap() });
        }

        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Key", "Key");
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn() { HeaderText = "Status" });

        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Key";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "value";

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = items;
```

and **MyItem** is sth. like this:

```
class MyItem
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public Image value { get; set; }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: Sorry still the same problem

Comment: But you checked the file is definitiv there? Because it seems like there is no image found or sth.

Comment: no the file is there I put it myself just to test the function.

Comment: What about Image image = Image.FromFile("yourfile.jpg");
Works by me fine.

Comment: But i just want the icon of file not the image because sometimes it's a pdf file.

Comment: Maybe you just added the Icon to the wrong Property? and it should be .Image instead of .Icon?

Comment: I don't think so I want to get the icon and put it in DataGridView column.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you want me to do.When I use the Image property it works fine and I can see the image in the column, so it means that the application is reading the file without problems but still can't get the icon.

Comment: thnx bro and sorry for taking your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following:

- Image file is surely there.
- Image file is not corrupt (you can access it with image viewers).
- You have permission to access drive C: (if not, run the program as admin).

If the above hold true, try copying the file into the project. I don't actually understand why you would keep your image file outside the project. This simplifies things further, since you can use relative paths to access the file.